# Easy way to display alert

Tags: user-interface, pharo, spec-ui

Is it possible to display an alert for user in an easy way? Something like:

```
save

  title
    ifEmpty: [ 'Title cannot be empty' alert ]
    ifNotEmpty: [ "…do the saving…" ]
```

so that if `title` ivar will be empty user will see the dialog with appropriate message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be:

```
self inform: 'Title cannot be empty'
```

but to be honest, I'm not happy with it, because is like a growl notification.

Most of the time, that's exactly what you want, but some times you need a modal notification... anyway, that's what you need :)

Comment: Yes, but this is really about informing. I was wandering if there is an easy way of opening dialog window with message

Comment: well... that's what I said is missing. I would really like something like "informModal:" around... :(

Answer (score 2):

You can (somewhat) tweak the dialog window before showing it up with a block.

Like centering it on screen with a red border.

```
UIManager default 
      alert: 'Something is wrong' 
      title: 'Issue ahead' 
      configure: [ :d | d position: Display center; borderColor: Color red].
```

Comment: nice , I really like UIManager and I am surprised it does not pop up more often in these type of questions :)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is

for a typical error dialog you can use this piece of code

```
UIManager default abort: 'Title cannot be empty'.
```

for a growl messages that the user has not to click on ok button you can use this

```
UIManager default inform: 'Data has been saved'.
```

UIManager has actually a lot of options on this and a lot of messages you can use. Just explore the class and I am sure you will find something that fits your needs.